# Use of undefined constant STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_0_CLIENT

Tags: php, laravel, email

Laravel 5.2

Local Enviornment

I am trying to get a console command set up for notifying me by email when certain date values are coming up compared to the current date.

When I type the command I get this error returned.

```
Mail::send('emails.ssl-expire-notice', ['hello' => 'hello'], function ($message) {
            $message->from('example@domain.com', 'Laravel');
            $message->to('garrett@p11.com');
        });
```

Error Message:

```
Use of undefined constant STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_0_CLIENT - assumed 'STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_0_CLIENT'
```

can't find anything about this. Not sure exactly whats going on here. I am using sendgrid for my mail server and have all of that set in my .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Project Name"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@domain.com
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @miken32 Ahhh my path was using 5.5 when it should be on 5.6. I have updated that now and I don't get that error anymore. Now I get Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed